# How to find an element and a subgroup of a certain given order in $U(n)$

Tags: group-theory

> How can I find a subgroup of order $k$ in $U(n)$ or an element of
>   order $k$?

Here $U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$.

For example, if $n=700$ and $k=6$ I know that since $700=5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 2^2$ we have $U(700) = U(7) \oplus U(4) \oplus U(5^2)$ and since $U(7) \cong \mathbb Z_6$ a cyclic subgroup of order six exists.

But this doesn't solve the problem: now I have shown existence without actually finding the subgroup.

One thing I could do now is to calculate the orders of all the elements of $U(700)$ until I find one of order $6$ but I suspect there is a more intelligent way of finding elements of given orders.

> Is there a more intelligent method than calculating the orders of the
>   elements?

Comment: Please state what you mean with $U(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there is no formula to find primitive roots of unity but there are faster methods than brute force.

This article may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots